# LinkedList Recursion

Tags: java, linked-list

```
public class LinkedList {

    Node head = null;
    int nodeCount= 0;
    int counter = 0;

    LinkedList() {
        head = null;
    }

   public Node reverseTest(Node L) {
       if(L == null || L.next ==null) {
           return L;
       }

       Node remainingNode =  reverseTest(L.next);
       Node cur = remainingNode;
       while(cur.next !=null) {
           cur=cur.next;
       }

       L.next = null;
       cur.next = L;

       return  remainingNode;
   }
}

public class LinkedListDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkedList FriendList = new LinkedList();
        FriendList.insertNode("First");
        FriendList.insertNode("Second");
        FriendList.insertNode("Third");
        FriendList.insertNode("Fourth");

        FriendList.reverseTest(FriendList.head);
        // FriendList.copyObject(FriendList.head);
        String NameList = FriendList.toString();
        System.out.println(NameList);
        System.out.println("Finish");

    }
}
```

Confusion:

In the `reverseTest` method which is recursive after returning first L value from this line

```
if(L == null || L.next ==null) {
    return L;
}
```

we pass the value to `remainingNode` in this line

```
Node remainingNode =  reverseTest(L.next);
```

then we copy it to `cur` variable

```
 Node cur = remainingNode;
```

when we reach the line

```
cur.next = L;
```

it updates the `cur.next` with L, but it also updates

```
remainingNode.next = L
```

I don't understand. How? Can someone point me what should I look into?

Comment: If the while loop is not executed, because cur.next == NULL, cur and remainingNode are the same and updating next on cur will update it on remainingNode also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cur and remaining node are pointing to the same memory address. whatever you do to one will affect the other.  You want them to point to two different memory locations.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `while` loop in between `Node cur = remainingNode;` and `cur.next = L`:

```
while(cur.next !=null){
    cur=cur.next;
}
```

Hence, `cur` and `remainingNode` are not pointing to the same node. `cur` is now pointing to the last node of the list starting from `remainingNode`.

Answer (score 0):

Fist the head node will be changed by the reversal, so it is an in-out parameter. In java: in-parameter + result:

```
friendList.head = FriendList.reverseTest(FriendList.head);
```

The shown code loops/recurses much. The reason being that the recursion is done on the rest, and then the first element appended at the tail. *Quite unnatural, circumstantial.*

For a recursive solution, one should go a more natural solution. For such recursive solutions, an extra parameter helps. Here we have a to-do-list and a done-list as parameters.

Now you can delay, use "future" results:

```
public Node reverseTest(Node L) {
      return reverseRecursively(L, null);
}

private Node reverseRecursively(Node node, Node reversed) {
      if (node == null) {
          return reversed;
      }
      Node next = node.next;
      node.next = reversed;
      reversed = node;
      return reverseRecursively(next, reversed);
}
```

Here `node` will be the sublist of to-dos, and `reversed` the partial result of already reversed nodes.

This is called tail-recursion as there is a single recursive call at the end. So it can easily be written iteratively as a single loop.